# Android Studio - ignores return statement and crashes when debugging

Tags: android, android-studio

Everything was working last night and now all sorts of weirdness.

First, I had a public static method. The declaration was on 2 lines...

```
public static PlaceOfInterest createFromBitmap(long id, String name, double latitude,
    double longitude, Bitmap thumbnail) {

    if (thumbnail == null)
        return new PlaceOfInterest(id, name, latitude, longitude, "");

    // Shrink and encode the image
    Bitmap encodedImage = ...

    return new PlaceOfInterest(id, name, latitude, longitude, encodedImage);
}
```

When debugging, android studio only showed values for the first 3 parameters and nothing for longitude and thumbnail, said it couldn't find them. After disabling instant run that problem subsided but now it crashes.

I pass in `null` for thumbnail. When debugging, it gets to the first return. I step over and instead of returning the position moves straight to the second return, skipping the code inbetween. When I step over this time it just crashes and doesn't end up in the callers try-catch.

Lots of uninstalls, cleans, rebuilds later and still failing.

Android Studio 2.3
Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Android Plugin Version: 2.3.0
Gradle version: 3.3
Emulator using nexus 7 with API version 23

**EDIT:**

Last thing from logcat...

```
03-11 01:43:01.390 3737-3737/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-11 01:43:01.828 3737-3737/com.trippin.walkietalkies W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.trippin.walkietalkies-2/lib/x86
03-11 01:43:01.843 3737-3737/com.trippin.walkietalkies I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace say happened?

Comment: What stacktrace? I have a `catch (Exception e)` but it just crashes before entering it.

Comment: If something crashes, there's a logcat. Can you show it?

Comment: Im very new to android dev :) the whole log disappeared then something appeared, that disappeared, then something else appeared. I've added the final bit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a bug with Marshmallow and AVD. I've changed to Nougat and it no longer crashes.